# persist() always creates new node

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am having problems with indexing/persisting with SDN 2.0.0.RELEASE and Neo4j 1.5.

I have a domain class "Word" which basically looks like this:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Word {

@GraphId
Long graphId;

@Indexed(indexType = IndexType.SIMPLE, indexName = "Word_wordString")
private String wordString;

@RelatedTo(direction = Direction.INCOMING, elementClass = Sentence.class, type = "HAS")
private Set<Sentence> sentences;

public Word() {
}

public Word(String wordString) {
    setWordString(wordString);
}
}
```

I am persisting words with this method:

```
private void persistWord(Sentence sentence, Word word) {
System.out.println("checking index for wordString: "
                + word.getWordString());
Word existingWord = wordRepository.findByPropertyValue(
                "wordString", word.getWordString());
if (existingWord != null) {
    existingWord.addSentence(sentence);
    existingWord.persist();
    System.out.println("persisted already existing word "
                    + existingWord);
} else {
    word.persist();
    System.out.println("persisted word " + word);
}
```

It's supposed to check if the word is already in the graph, if so i change some attributes on the object returned by the wordRepository, then persist the changes (-> if (existingWord != null)). If the word is not in the graph yet it is just persisted (-> else).

This however always creates a new node for every word, even when it exists in the graph. So to speak, persist() always creates a new node.
After there are two words with the same wordString in the graph, the repository method throws:

```
More than one element in org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex$1@1181df3. First element is 'Node[45]' and the second element is 'Node[83]'
```

What's going on?

I am also wondering what the difference between IndexType.SIMPLE,IndexType.POINT and IndexType.FULLTEXT is. (It's not in the API or the Good Relations guide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the problem:

When I persisted the words I always added them to the "words" Set of the current sentence and I set the sentence property of the Word. I think that was the reason why some words were persisted multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Tobias,

could you check if the `findByPropertyValue` that takes an index name as first parameter and pass in your "Word_wordString" index would help. Your repository has to extend then NamedIndexRepository` as well. The repository should take your custom-index name into account automatically anyway.

You might also try to leave off the separate index-name then it would default to the simple class name, aka `Word` which would be used automatically.

What kinds of words are you using are they just alphanumeric characters or other, chars like spaces, line-feed etc in there?

Comment: I have made my WordRepository extend GraphRepository and NamedIndexRepository and used `wordRepository.findByPropertyValue("Word_wordString","wordString", word.getWordString());` to check for existing words.

The code is the same as in my original question except for the line where I check the index. What happens is, the first time a word is to be persisted, the index returns null as expected, the new word is persisted. The second time, the index returns an object instance, as expected. The third time however, the index throws the same exception as in my original question.

Comment: Therefore I figure, that the persist method always creates a new node and or entry in the index! I will check what characters the words contain, but for testing purposes I trim them all when they are initially set.